# react native with expo:Run project on gennymotion problem

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, expo

I created a new react native project by expo init projectname  command.
and run that by expo start command in project library.this project run perfect on real device but this error comes when trying run on gennymotion:

> Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb: failed to
>   install C:\Users\Arash.expo\android-apk-cache\Exponent-2.12.2.apk:
>   Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse
>   /data/app/vmdl904453318.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]

gennymotion device developer mode enabled and adb directory in gennymotion settings is custom.

it realy make me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved  the problem :try deleting the c:/users/.expo/android-apk-cache directory .
fixed it for me