# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI Expo

Tags: android, expo, react-native

recently I update the versions of my application of expo,
And tried to run in simulator IOS and everything works good, but when I tried to run in android simulator throw me this error:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb: failed to install /Users/MY_USER/.expo/android-apk-cache/Exponent-2.21.3.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1520492880.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #134): intent tag may have at most one data type.]
```

- I tried to remove folder /.expo
- also I tried to remove the files inside of .expo/android-apk-cache

as said in this post: [react native with expo:Run project on gennymotion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006611/react-native-with-exporun-project-on-gennymotion-problem)

but dosent work, any idea?

Comment: there was an intermittent issue with the expo go app for android 11, you can run `expo client:install:android` to get the latest version that will resolve this issue